# Meta.SE's question listing is taller

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, question-lists

The individual questions take up a lot more vertical space in the question listing compared to any other site.

As you can see in the screenshot below, SO can fit about 5 and 1/2 questions in the same space that Meta.SE fits 3 questions.

[image: SO vs Meta.SE]

Is this on purpose or because the site is still being worked on?

Comment: That formatting certainly doesn't look right. What browser/OS/window size are you using?

Comment: Latest version of Chrome on Windows 7, maximized window at 2560x1440.

Comment: It definitely does not look like that to me. You might have some broken style sheets cached.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I just visited the new Meta for the first time on this computer. I will clear my cache and try again...

Comment: Are you zoomed in, by any chance?

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes, my Chrome defaults to 110% or else it is very hard to read anything at this resolution. The problem does not exist on any other Stack Exchange site. Zooming out fixes it though.

Comment: We don't normally support zoomed in (or out) views, but I see your point. We should at least be consistent between different sites, and one level of zooming shouldn't be enough to break the layout completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this on purpose or because the site is still being worked on?

Neither! This is a bug that went unnoticed during development because we don't tend to run at anything other than the normal 100% zoom.

As I've noted before in various discussions, we don't really support zoomed in views. *However*, one level of zooming really shouldn't break things as badly as it does here, nor should zooming behaviour be wildly inconsistent between our various sites.

Jin pushed a fix for this earlier today, and it will go live with the next build. You should see improvement as of rev 2014.4.23.2184.

Comment: This problem also exists on the new Academia.SE. It was fine when it was still in beta. Will this fix also apply to it?

Comment: @AustinHenley Yes, and also Graphic Design.